# Getting PHP $_POST values by index?

Tags: php, post, indexing

I'm curious, more than anything - is it possible to get a PHP value posted? i.e. `$_POST['foo']` via some kind of indexing? i.e. `$_POST[0]`?

(`$_POST[0]` does not work by the way)

Comment: $POST's cannot be accessed as an index directly. But here is a cheap and simple solution:

$myPost = array_values($_POST);
echo $myPost[0];

This will echo the first value posted.

Comment: I actually don't see the use for accessing $_POST values by numeric index - would anyone care to enlighten me on a case where it would be practical?

Comment: You usually do not want to care about the order of values, they highly depend on influencing factors like order of input elements in HTML - which might change because of layout changes. Do not depend on them, use the names - because you should know them, it is your form after all.

Comment: Sure; I've been considering creating an API for a piece of online software im developing. When posting to the API one function may require 2 values, another 5. Sending a post to the API which then posts values to a relevant function would be difficult unless we know the names of all the relevant post. In addition we then start setting a load of "null" in various function variables if we were to use field names of non meaningful values (postVar1, postVar2...). I figured I could extract a "function name" from post[0], then post the rest of that array to a relevant function via a "switch, case".

Comment: ^ I think that made sense...I have trouble getting thoughts out of the head sometimes!
@Sven, youre right. I wouldnt normally use it, especially not in a normal form. The way I intend to use it is via another webpage which posts to my api script. I would give it a format requirement, i.e. $function, $var1, $var2, $var3 ...etc.

Comment: You could name several inputs `name="postVar[]"`, this will make you able to access the variables by `$_POST[postVar][x]`, where x is an integer and be able to iterate over them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible: you cannot fetch values from an associative array by numeric indexes (because, as clearly noted in [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), PHP does not distinguish between indexed and associative arrays).

That's why some functions ([PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and its siblings, for example) that return arrays take an additional param to control the 'type' of indexes in the array returned: numeric (`FETCH_NUM`), string (`FETCH_ASSOC`) or both (`FETCH_BOTH`, the default value). )

The closest you might get with reindexing:

```
$myPost = array_values($_POST);
```

Comment: Ah I see...I've never really looked at a POST as an array until just now...your solution provides a more than ample answer - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

not that i'm aware of, check out a print_r($_POST) to see all goodies that you can access.  You could **iterate** over the values with:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.' '.$value."\n";
}
```

You could throw in an `$i++` if you wanted to keep track of a count ....

Answer (score 0):

You can take data stored in $_POST variables and store them into indexed elements.  But they are not stored as an indexed element initially.